# Spring Security 3.2: Prevent Direct Object Reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, esapi

I expose a Spring REST service like this..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = Constant.ACCEPT_APPLICATION_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public IndividualProviderDto showJson(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    IndividualProviderDto individualProviderDto = individualProviderService.findIndividualProvider(id);
    if (SecurityUtils.getCurrentLogin().equals(individualProviderDto.getUserName())) {
        individualProviderDto.setCredential("");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(Constant.CONTENT_TYPE, Constant.APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF8);
        return individualProviderDto;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("User not found"); 
}
```

In the above code I am explicitly making a check to ensure that the id belongs to the logged in USER.

```
SecurityUtils.getCurrentLogin().equals(individualProviderDto.getUserName()
```

This check has to be applied wherever I need to protect a resource. Of course I can have an Aspect and apply it from one place using pointcut expressions. I have also heard of ESAPI that forges the url

but I was wondering if Spring Security Configuration provides something out of the box, so that I don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? A note: it is probably easier to just get the user from the one currently logged in.

Comment: Consider the URI www.myapp.com/account/123. I'm wondering what is considered best practice in Spring Security for authorizing direct object references e.g. the user uses their browser's location box to update the url to www.myapp.com/account/124 which they should not have permission to (their account is ID 123, not 124).

Comment: What you say is correct as well, i.e just call www.myapp.com/account and let the server figure out the id of the current logged in users, but lets say each admin has 10 users under him, so the only way he could query the user is thru the id isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security is not the answer -- it provides facility for *authentication* and *authorization*. Checking availability of a particular entity (in your case `id`) should be a part of service layer, as it's already implemented in your code.